# print objects in common in two character objects

Tags: r, string, object, character

I have two character objects, I need to see how many characters they have in common and then print them. I have no problem seeing how many they have in common, but I can't seem to figure out the code to print them. Here's a simple exemple:

```
LETTERS
list <- c("A", "H", "J", "K")
length(na.exclude(pmatch(LETTERS[1:20],list[1:3]))) 
print(pmatch(LETTERS[1:20],list[1:3]))
```

This prints:

```
  LETTERS
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S"
[20] "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
  list <- c("A", "H", "J", "K")
  length(na.exclude(pmatch(LETTERS[1:20],list[1:3])))
[1] 3
  print(pmatch(LETTERS[1:20],list[1:3]))
[1]  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA  2 NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

So I know that there are 3 in common and I know their positions but how do I make it print "A" "H" "J"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `%in%`

```
> LETTERS[LETTERS %in% list]
[1] "A" "H" "J" "K"
```

For your example:

```
myletters<-LETTERS[1:20]
> myletters[myletters %in% list[1:3]]
[1] "A" "H" "J"
```

Alternative: using `pmatch` as suggested by you

```
pmatch(list[1:3],myletters) # gives the indices
[1]  1  8 10

myletters[pmatch(list[1:3],myletters)] # get the letters
[1] "A" "H" "J"
```

Comment: This is a much better approach (@metrics)  but using `list[na.omit(pmatch(LETTERS[1:20],list[1:3]))]` with yours would have worked. and don't write over list as it's an R base object.  see `?list`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the final result as a set (duplicates removed), use this:

```
intersect(LETTERS, c("A", "H", "J"))
```

If you want to use partial matching, you must observe that `pmatch` does *not* allow more than one element in the first input matching the same one in the second. Notice the difference:

```
mylist <- c("B","A","B","2")

> pmatch(mylist, LETTERS)
[1]  2  1 NA NA

> Vectorize(pmatch, "x")(mylist, LETTERS)
 B  A  B  2 
 2  1  2 NA
```

Now, if you want to print the elements of `mylist` that match (partially) with the elements of, say, `LETTERS`, keeping the order and duplicates, you can use this:

```
> mylist[!is.na(Vectorize(pmatch, "x")(mylist, LETTERS))]
[1] "B" "A" "B"
```